# Rails collection_radio_buttons with bootstrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection that I am using to filter records. Unfortunately the bootstrap styling is not working.

```
= collection_radio_buttons :ptype, :id, Ptype.all, :id, :part_type, {:checked => session[:ptype_id]}, {:onchange => "ptype_set(value)", :class => "radio-inline"}
```

It is producing this...

```
<input checked="checked" class="radio-inline" id="ptype_id_1" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="ptype_id_1">Welded</label>

<input class="radio-inline" id="ptype_id_2" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="2" />
<label for="ptype_id_2">Laser/Formed</label>

<input class="radio-inline" id="ptype_id_3" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="3" />
<label for="ptype_id_3">Bolt_on</label>

<input class="radio-inline" id="ptype_id_4" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="4" />
<label for="ptype_id_4">Machined</label>

<input class="radio-inline" id="ptype_id_5" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="5" />
<label for="ptype_id_5">Empty</label>
```

In the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls), it shows that `class="radio-inline"` should be part of the `label` and not part of the `input` (as shown below).

```
<input checked="checked" id="ptype_id_1" name="ptype[id]" onchange="ptype_set(value)" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="ptype_id_1" class="radio-inline">Welded</label>
```

This set is purely being used as a selector to fire off the Javascript for filtering, so I do not need it nested in a `form_for`. However, I even tried that and it did not work either.

Is there a way to make the `class="radio-inline"` move into the label tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck: [`collection_radio_buttons` accepts a block and you can pass a builder object to it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons). The `label` and `radio_button` methods on that builder accept an HTML options hash argument and a block, and you can use the `text` method to get the actual option label text. In Slim you could try this:

```
= collection_radio_buttons :ptype, :id, Ptype.all, :id, :part_type do |b|
  = b.label(:class => 'radio-inline') { b.radio_button(:checked => session[:ptype_id], :onchange => 'ptype_set(value)') + b.text }
```

For the inline radio buttons, Bootstrap expects the input to be nested inside the label. That will render your radio buttons in the way you are expecting. Enjoy!

Comment: ```:checked => session[:ptype_id]``` it doesnt work for me because of using ```data-toggle ="buttons"``` how can I solve it?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you post your code in a new question? I can look at it in depth there.